# Submit a dask process only if it's not active in any of the workers

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Assume I have N workers. I need to submit a program with dask `client.submit` in one of the workers, but only if it's not running in any of the workers. Any hints on how can this be achieved? Can I get this information from the scheduler?

Comment: can you give an example setup that would help us understand the use case & setup? ideally a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask tokenises your call to a function submitted with `client.submit` (or delayed or any of the high-level APIs). So if you submit new work that's identical to something already running in the cluster, it will not repeat the task, but wait for the completion of the already-running one. (You can turn off this behaviour by using keyword `pure=False`)

Here we get the same random number four times:

```
In [35]: client.gather([client.submit(random.random) for _ in range(4)])
Out[35]: [0.609188678994237, 0.609188678994237, 0.609188678994237, 0.609188678994237]
```